# Flutter unable to add title on AppBarTheme

Tags: flutter, dart

I was working on a Flutter project and I tried to add the `title` parameter to `AppBarTheme` but it gave me an error. This is the code:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      accentColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
      fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
      appBarTheme: 
        AppBarTheme(textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
          title: const TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
            fontSize: 20,
            )
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

The error was: `The named parameter 'title' isn't defined.`
How can I solve this?

Comment: Please provide the entire code instead of a photo or screenshot so that it will be easy to debug for others and provide a solution for you.

Comment: My bad I am new here, fine I am going to edit it right now, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the way :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('AppBar titleTextStyle')),
      body: Center(child: Text('Hello World')),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
          titleTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          backwardsCompatibility: false, // !!!
        ),
      ),
      home: Home(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add title to AppBarTheme, you can only provide the TextStyle for the title in themeData and add the title in AppBar like this:

```
AppBar(
    title: Text(
      'your text',
      // You need to add this line
      style: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.TextStyle,
    ),
),
```